# Query large table and do logic in code OR do a lot of queries.. Which one is more efficient?

Tags: android, performance, sqlite

I have a very large table with ~90000 row, each row containing 10 columns.. I need to get some data from the Database.. In the worst case, I need to query 7500 row, but often its around ~4000 rows..

Each row has a column called "LineNumber", and each ~10 rows have the same LineNumber, which starts from 1...
For all the rows that have the same LineNumber, I need to get the Lowest and Highest numbers from a column called RATING..

I can get all those ~4000 rows, and then pass on each one of those lines and do some logic to get the highest or lowest..
OR I can query for each LineNumber I'm interested in and have the query get me the highest and lowest, which will be easier..

Which one of these 2 ways is more efficient?

Answer (score 1):

I would stand for query. At first glance the query looks quite simple:

```
SELECT LineNumber MIN(RATING) MAX(RATING) FROM <YOUR_TABLE> WHERE... GROUP BY LineNumber
```

This should give exactly what you want (if I understand right)

Answer (score 1):

I had some problem like you, but in my case was with Dates, geting the 'after' and 'before'...

I did in the code, I query all the data that I need, then I compared the dates, in ~40k lines the time was near 20 sec...

So I tried put the logic in the SQL, when I get the query, I do the the compares, and for my surprise now the query, with all I need do everything in less than 2 sec...

My advice is to try first put the logic in the query, if doesn't satisfactory the results, try in the code and see what's the best.

Good Luck!

[]'s
Bertan